# Extract words from two lists from sentences in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have text in a panda dataframe

I also have two lists of words. I want to see if elements of these lists exist in one sentence and extract all pairings separated by a colon (also if not paired)

Eg

```
   patternAnatomy="oesophagus|stomach|duodenum"
    patternEvent="clip|RFA|balloon|biopsy"
```

example text:

```
There was a need to place a clip in the oesophagus. One biopsy was taken. There is a long duodenum. The stomach had a balloon placed
```

Should extract: `oesophagus:clip,:biopsy,duodenum:,stomach:balloon`

To get individual sentence I have tried

```
nlp = English()
nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer'))

def tokenizeAndList(text):
    
    if isinstance(text, str):
        doc = nlp(text)
        return [sent.string.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
    else:
        return text
        
Mypanda['findings2']=Mypanda['findings'].map(tokenizeAndList,na_action='ignore')
```

and then:

```
Mypanda['findings2'].apply(lambda row: row.findall("("+patternEvent+")",re.IGNORECASE))
```

but this fails and anyway would search only for elements from one of the lists only

Comment: use lambda row:  row.str.extract(......)

Answer (score 0):

```
k=patternAnatomy+'|'+patternEvent
df['extract']=df['text'].str.findall(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function and then apply it to the dataframe:

```
text = 'There was a need to place a clip in the oesophagus. One biopsy was taken. There is a long duodenum. The stomach had a balloon placed'
patternAnatomy = "oesophagus|stomach|duodenum"
patternEvent = "clip|RFA|balloon|biopsy"

def split_text(text, patternAnatomy, patternEvent):
    s = [sentence.split() for sentence in text.split('.')]
    ana = patternAnatomy.split('|')
    eve = patternEvent.split('|')
    whitelist = ana + eve

    l = list()
    for sentence in s:
        l_ana = list()
        l_eve = list()
        for word in sentence:
            if word in ana:
                l_ana.append(word)
            if word in eve:
                l_eve.append(word)
        l.append([l_ana, l_eve])

    return ['_'.join(tup[0])+':'+'_'.join(tup[1]) for tup in l]

split_text(text, patternAnatomy, patternEvent)
# Out[14]: ['oesophagus:clip', ':biopsy', 'duodenum:', 'stomach:balloon']
```

It would be better to provide s, ana, eve, whitelist variables as parameters  instead of calculating them each time.